# Explain how this C++ function returns an array

Tags: c++, arrays, stack, return-value, function-pointers

I found this code online http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/6644/#msg30551 which is supposed to return an array from a c++ function. I would like an explanation illustrating how this function operates with respect to memory allocation, stacks, heaps, pointers etc.

```
int *f(size_t s){
    int *ret=new int[s];
    for (size_t a=0;a<s;a++)
        ret[a]=a;
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't return an array. It returns a pointer to the first element of a dynamically allocated array.

Answer (score 3):

I.

```
int *ret=new int[s];
```

1. allocate memory for `ret` on the stack - this is an `int` pointer
2. allocate continuous memory with size `s * sizeof(int)` on the heap
3. make `ret` to point to the first element of the allocated memory (from 2.)

---

II.

```
for (size_t a=0;a<s;a++)
    ret[a]=a;
```

1. allocates memory on the stack for `a`
2. loop through the allocated memory in I., assigning values to each element
3. After the end of the `for`-statement, `a` is no longer accessible (it's available only in the `for`)

---

III.

```
return ret;
```

return *a copy of the `ret` pointer*, which points to the first element of the created in I. array, initialized in II.

After the `return`, `ret` is "destroyed".

---

The caller of this function must not forget to deallocate (free) this memory, invoking `delete[]`.

For example:

```
int * my_array = f( 6 );
// do sth with my_array
delete[] my_array;
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the function doesn't return an array of `int`s (i.e. `int[N]`). What it returns is a pointer to an `int` (`int *`). It turns out that this pointer points to the first element of an array of `s` elements of type `int`.

Notice that the memory is allocated with `new`:

```
int *ret = new int[s];
```

Therefore, the array of `int`s pointed by `ret` has dynamic storage duration. Among other things, this implies that

1) the compiler will not automatically call each array element's destructor. (In this case this isn't a problem because the elements are of type `int` but could be if, instead, the elemets where of a class type with a non-trivial destructor.)

2) the compiler will not automatically free the allocated memory.

To contrast, consider the following code:

```
void g() {
    int p[10]; // allocates 10 integer in the stack
    // use p ...
}
```

When `g` terminates the compiler will perform the aforementioned operations. For this to work, the size of the array (10 in this example) must be set at compile time. If you don't know the size at compile time than you need `new` as in the original code.

For dynamic allocated arrays, it's the programmer's responsibility to ensure that the two aforementioned operations are performed when the array is no longer needed. To accomplish this, you must call `delete[]`:

```
delete[] p; // where p is a `int*` with the same value as `ret`
```

In practice, this is more difficult than it seems due to the possibility of
exceptions being thrown. For instance, consider this code

```
void foo() {
    int* p = f(10); // where f is in the question
    // ... use the array pointed by p
    a_function_that_might_throw();
    delete[] p;
}
```

If `a_function_that_might_throw` does throw an exception then the execution
never reachs the point where `p` is deleted. In this case, the memory
allocated by `new` (inside `f`) will not be freed (it leaks) until the
program terminates.

To avoid this problem, instead of a raw pointer (e.g. `int*`) it's better to
use a smart pointer (e.g. `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`).

Finally, by default, the memory allocated by `new` is heap memory. However,
you can change this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
int *ret=new int[s];
```

This line defines a `int*` called `ret` with automatic storage duration. It initialises `ret` with the pointer returned by the *new-expression* `new int[s]`. This *new-expression* creates an array of `s` `int`s with dynamic storage duration, returning a pointer to the first element in that array.

So we now have two objects: an `int*` with automatic storage duration and an `int[]` with dynamic storage duration.

```
for (size_t a=0;a<s;a++)
```

This is a `for` statement. The *for-init-statement* defines a `size_t` object called `a` and initialises it to 0. The *condition* checks whether `a` is less than `s`. The final *expression* increments `a`. This means that `a` loops in the range `[0, s)`.

```
ret[a]=a;
```

This assigns the value of `a` to the `a`th element in `ret`. That is `ret[0]` will have the value `0`, `ret[1]` will have the value `1`, and so on.

The `a` object is now destroyed because it had automatic storage duration and we have reached the end of its scope (the `for` statement).

```
return ret;
```

This returns the value of `ret`, which as you remember was an `int*`. The return value of the function is therefore an `int*` pointing at the first element of the dynamically allocated array.

The `ret` object is now destroyed because it had automatic storage duration and we have reached the end of its scope (the `f` function). Note that this is just the pointer inside the function. The dynamically allocated array still exists and the returned pointer still points to it.

You must, at some later point, remember to `delete[]` the returned pointer.

Answer (score 0):

```
int *ret =  new int[s];
```

This dynamically (~ on the heap) allocates an array of `s` integers and stores a pointer to it (actually, to its first element) in `ret`.

I believe the rest of the function is straightforward.

So the function is handing back a pointer to a dynamically allocated array. It's not really safe; if the caller does not store the return value and later call `delete[]` on it, it will leak.